# split a character from a number with multiple digits

Tags: string, r

I have a column in a dataframe where the values are letter-number combinations like G1, K8, A132, etc. I want to split the letter from the number but retain the number as a single number. I have been using strsplit but this gives a list of values as seen below where I would liek to have the output of `G` and `10`:

```
x <- "G10"
strsplit(x, "")[[1]][1]
"G"
strsplit(x, "")[[1]][-1]
"1" "0"
```

this leads to the predictable downstream problems when I try to use the numbers as numbers. Here is a  `paste` example where I would like to get "somethingelse_10":

```
z <-strsplit(x, "")[[1]][-1]
paste("somethingelse",z, sep="_")
"somethingelse_1" "somethingelse_0"
```

Is there an easy way to split numbers from letters?

Comment: Is the format always a single letter followed by some number?

Comment: in this case there is only a single letter before a number of one or more digits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **stringr** package often has convenient functions for this sort of thing:

```
require(stringr)
str_extract(c("A1","B2","C123"),"[[:upper:]]")
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
str_extract(c("A1","B2","C123"),"[[:digit:]]+")
#[1] "1"   "2"   "123"
```

That assumes that each element has exactly one "letter" part, and one "number" part, since `str_extract` is just pulling the first instance of a match.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `gsub` to eliminate all non-digit, or all digit characters like so:

```
> x <- "A3"
> gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",x)
"3"
> gsub("[:digit:]","",x)
"A"
```

And then you can use `as.numeric` to convert from string to number, if you desire.

Comment: You could add a solution for extracting letters (see joran's answer). In fact, one could write a function to extract letters and numbers and have `apply` work on the data.frame column. :)

Comment: @aaronjg to get letters you need an extra pair of []

Answer (score 4):

If as your comment suggests you just have a single letter followed by one or more digits you could do something similar to this:

```
x <- c("G10", "X1231", "y14522")
# Just grab the first letter
letter <- substring(x, 1, 1)
letter
# [1] "G" "X" "y"
# Grab everything except the first character and convert to numeric
number <- as.numeric(substring(x, 2, nchar(x)))
number
#[1]    10  1231 14522
```