# How do I use tidyr::separate to separate a factor including a number?

Tags: r

I have a tibble where I want to separate a  column that also includes one number. I want to separate it into two columns. I would like the seperator: "sep" to be equal to a digit. (So that one column would have the number, and the other the fctr.

```
separate(x, into =  c("fctr", "number"), sep ="??what do I put here?")
```

example:
on the "week_days", I want to separate the numbers from the characters.
I want the numbers to appear in another column.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a reproducible data set (you can use `dput`)?

Comment: Hey, dont know if I am able to reproduce.. hehe. Though I provided a picture. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split character data into numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756360/split-character-data-into-numbers-and-letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sep should be equal to: `"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])"`.

```
df <- data.frame(week_days=as.factor(paste0(sample(letters,10),sample(1:10,10))))
separate(df,week_days,into=c("letter","digit"),sep= "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])")

   letter digit
1       u     7
2       a     4
3       m     2
4       k     9
5       b     6
6       t     5
7       h     8
8       v     3
9       r     1
10      i    10
```

Comment: thank you! I also noticed that I am able to separate by possition witch helped me out in this case. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this answered your question, you can accept it.