# R separate numbers and characters in a string

Tags: r, string, split

I have a string

```
rule <- "X[,16] <= -0.664 & X[,11] <= -2.1891 & X[,17] >= -0.4138"
```

I want to split a string into two parts

```
num_part = c(16 , -0.664 , 11 , -2.1891 , 17 , -0.4138)
char_part = c("X[,]<= & X[,] <= & X[,] >=")
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756360/split-character-data-into-numbers-and-letters) but I couldn't apply any of the eight examples to my data

Comment: Try `str_remove_all(rule, "[0-9.-]+"); str_remove_all(rule, "\\[|\\]|\\>=|<=|&|X|,")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use

```
library(stringr)
 scan(text = str_remove_all(rule, "\\[|\\]|\\>=|<=|&|X|,"), what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)
[1] 16.0000 -0.6640 11.0000 -2.1891 17.0000 -0.4138
str_remove_all(rule, "[0-9.-]+")
[1] "X[,] <=  & X[,] <=  & X[,] >= "
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one go:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(rule) %>%
  mutate(num = str_extract_all(rule, "[\\d.-]+"),
         char = str_extract_all(rule, "[^\\d.-]+"))
                                                      rule                                  num
1 X[,16] <= -0.664 & X[,11] <= -2.1891 & X[,17] >= -0.4138 16, -0.664, 11, -2.1891, 17, -0.4138
                                      char
1 X[,, ] <= ,  & X[,, ] <= ,  & X[,, ] >=
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)

rule <- "X[,16] <= -0.664 & X[,11] <= -2.1891 & X[,17] >= -0.4138"
num_part <- stringr::str_extract_all(rule, pattern = "[-+]?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?")
char_part <- stringr::str_remove_all(rule, "[0-9.-]+")
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `regmatches` (for `num_part`) and `gsub` (for `char_part`) with a pattern `pat` like below

```
> pat <- "-?(\\d+)?\\.?\\d+"

> as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(rule, gregexpr(pat, rule))))
[1] 16.0000 -0.6640 11.0000 -2.1891 17.0000 -0.4138

> gsub(pat, "", rule)
[1] "X[,] <=  & X[,] <=  & X[,] >= "
```